# Migrate Mysql database to AroraDB using percona xtrabackup

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, percona

I am trying to migrate data from mysql server to AWS arora db.For that i am trying to create a bakcup file first. but it is giving me below error

Warning: option 'datadir' has different values:
  '/var/lib/mysql' in defaults file
  '/mysqldata/mysql/' in SHOW VARIABLES
Error: failed to execute query SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the PROCESS privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: Does this happen when you create your backup, or when you import it? The error message is fairly clear. The userid you're using lacks a necessary privilege. Can you get your sysadmin to grant it?

Comment: Curious. Why do you desire to move to AuroraDB? Are you expecting better performance? I just want you to realize that Aurora is not a write-scale solution. (This is the most common misconception) You are still limited to writing to only 1 instance.

Answer (score 2):

As O.Jones said, the error message is quite obvious. It says the MySQL user you are using to execute xtrabackup does not have the necessary privileges to take said backup. The solution is to `GRANT PROCESS ON *.* TO backup_user@localhost;`